# slight difference between different unicode encodings

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have been attempting to create a Python implementation of a program of my friend written in js/c++, however we have encountered a slight difference in the encoding that prevent my program from achieving the same result. Through by a side channel I am able to resolve the issue, I would like to know how did the problem arise and how to prevent it from happening again in the future

The problem appears when our programs take a Unicode string, store the last significant byte into an array of bytes, and md5 hash it (doesn't have to be secure so md5 is okay) to produce a result. But in practice, our program exhibits different behaviors when encoding the string into bytes:

her program: 依然冰奈斯→[0x9d, 0x**3**6, 0xb0, 0x**4**8, 0xaf]

my program: 依然冰奈斯→[0x9d, 0x**b**6, 0xb0, 0x**8**8, 0xaf]

I attempted to encode it with various different codex(different versions of Unicode, hz, gb, cp, isos). None yields the result she has obtained in her program, and researching online for different unicode versions for simplified chinese did not provide insight to how this might happen, through this difference appears again when I encoded the string with [an online converter](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/), the difference arose again between the codices intended for web applications (css, U+, 0x formats) against the regular UTF-8 representations. But through browsing the encoding library, I found a ["Unicode_escape" codex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) that results in the same-last-byte sequence my friend's program has yielded. I would like to know that whether is there a specific codex other than UTF-8 that I should refer to, or how should I manipulate the data so that I can achieve the same result.

Comment: "store the last significant byte" is a significant randomizer, and not actually correct.  Pretty plain problem, you are using the wrong encoding.  She used utf-16 and takes the *first* byte of each byte-pair on a little-endian machine.  You used utf-8 and take the *last* byte of each utf-8 encoded glyph.  They all happen to generate 3 bytes per glyph in utf-8 for these characters and you use the 3rd.  You must use utf-16 as well.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me to solve the issue. I missed this possibility because when I encode characters in UTF-16`[i.encode(encoding = 'utf-16-le') for i in '依然冰奈斯']→
[b'\x9dO', b'6q', b'\xb0Q', b'HY', b'\xafe']`, python interactive window automatically converted portions of the UTF-16 with UTF-8 codex so that I wasn't able to make out the similarities. The following code made it possible to view in plain.`>>> [hex(i.encode(encoding = 'utf-16-le')[0]) for i in '依然冰奈斯']→['0x9d', '0x36', '0xb0', '0x48', '0xaf']`